# Show notification in Visual Basic.net

Tags: vb.net

Using Visual Basic .Net, I would like to receive a notification from Windows whenever either a new program or a shortcut is created in a particular path (let's assume for example: `C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\...\Programs\Startup`).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) for that path and handle the [`Created`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created.aspx) event.

[**FileSystemWatcher-Tutorial**](http://www.dotnetperls.com/filesystemwatcher)

Comment: Why? This one seems like it is exactly what you are looking for! I learned something from this. Thank you Tim :)